# How to find exact location of my lost iPhone

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I lost my iPhone.

I used Find My iPhone.

It is located in a furniture store which I have visited today.

I want to know where exactly is my iPhone located.

I have my portable WiFi hostspot and I can see that my lost iPhone is connecting to the WiFi hostspot.

But still this is not enough, I could not find it.

I used play sound, but unfortunately, I cannot hear anything. It appears that the sound played by iPhone is too low to be beneficial in such circumstances .

Is there an app that let me know the exact location of a devices connected to my WiFi or to my HotSpot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no app to do what you want. The accuracy of the GPS used by "find my phone" is not good enough to tell you where the phone is with the accuracy you desire. I would go back to the store and tell management what you are doing and then try calling your cell phone number. Maybe the phone's ringing volume is loud enough to hear. If you don't have access to another cell phone maybe you can use the store's phone to call.